# Place 5 images in arc shape in Android

Tags: android

I have 5 imageviews which I want to place in an arc shape. The center of the view would be the right hand bottom corner of the screen.Can anyone tell me how to create the custom view for it?

Comment: can you give us a screenshot sample of it?

Comment: do something with a canvas, perhaps..?

Answer (score 2):

you mean you want to arrange like this

[Link here](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu)

```
 android:layout_gravity="top|right" 
         sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
         sat:totalSpacingDegree="240"
```

//make changes and try your self

[image]

Comment: Thanks Padma Kumar, but the images should be arranged in the right hand bottom corner... you seems to have placed it in left hand bottom corner. Also I should be able to rotate the images on a fling. Any ideas how to do that  :) ?

Comment: @Debtaru I didnt placed the images. did you gone thru the link that i provided. do you mean that I want to do your work?